# How to install Nuget Package for Windows 64bit cmdlet version

Tags: powershell

Want to install `nuget package` for 64bit cmdlet and it is thworing me an error while the same is working on the 32bit version in the same machine.

When I enter `Get-PackageProvider` it is giving me error like `Get-PackageProvider : The term 'Get-PackageProvider' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet` but the same working on 32bit cmdlet (please check the image below).

How to solve this problem ?

[image]

Updating the Question with additional information:
[image]

Comment: What happens when you call `Import-Module PackageManagement` directly? Also, on the 32-bit check `(Get-Module PackageManagement).ModuleBase` to see where it's installed.